# jQuery.data() problem with arrays

Tags: jquery

```
for( var i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ){
    $('#item').data('level1', { 'level21': {i:'hello'}, 'level22': {i:'world'} } );
}
```

The keys for *level21* and *level22* is the string `"i"` and not a number 0-5 from the `var i`. *level21* should be six times `"hello"` and *level22* six times `"world"`.

How can I fix that?

Thanks & regards,

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build your `.data` value the hard way, you'll also need to build the data in the loop and set it afterwards:

```
data = { level21: { }, level22: { } };
for( var i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ){
    data.level21[i] = 'hello';
    data.level22[i] = 'world';
}
$('#item').data('level1', data);
```

You have to use the `[]` form of object access to get `i` evaluated. You also need to build the data first to avoid overwriting the `'level1'` every time through the loop.

Also, if you're only using contiguous integers starting at zero inside `data.level21` and `data.level22`, then simple arrays might be a better choice than objects:

```
// Note the "{}" -> "[]" change in here
data = { level21: [ ], level22: [ ] };
// The syntax is the same for the rest
```

Comment: @Alex: If you're only using numbers inside `data.level21` and `data.level22`, then arrays (`data = { level21: [ ], level22: [ ] };`) might be a better choice.